# How to grant permissions to ADB?

Tags: adb, permissions, shell, system-error

I can use ADB while in recovery mode (TWRP) so to use it normally, I followed [Android - Enable ADB from recovery](https://gist.github.com/varhub/7b9555cdd1e5ad785ffde2300fcfd0bd) to enable USB debugging. There is always an error while switching users, granting permissions, unhiding apps, using `am` and `pm` commands.

This is the error that always comes:

> Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.

How to grant permissions to ADB?

Answer (score 0):

Call "adb root" before calling "pm install -r xxx.apk"

Comment: It's true that this gets the job done of installing an app, but it doesn't address how to grant a permission to adb. :-)